# Could not find valid Docker environment when running java TestContainers in GitLab-CI and pulling Docker:dind from private registry

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, testcontainers, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run Java TestContainers from GitLab-CI, using Docker-in-Docker. For security reasons, I am only allowed to use images replicated to internal enterprise container registry.

When I run the job with the following configuration:

```yaml
test:
  image: internalregistry.azurecr.io/maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-17
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind
  stage: test
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  before_script:
    - echo "hub.image.name.prefix=internalregistry.azurecr.io/" > $HOME/.testcontainers.properties
  script:
    - mvn clean test
```

the job works, tests are successfully executed and pass.

However, I created an internal variation of the image:

```
docker pull docker:24.0.5-dind
docker tag docker:24.0.5-dind internalregistry.azurecr.io/docker:24.0.5-dind
docker push internalregistry.azurecr.io/docker:24.0.5-dind
```

and when I change the docker service to point to internal registry:

```yaml
  services:
    - internalregistry.azurecr.io/docker:24.0.5-dind
```

the pipeline no longer suceeds and fails with the following error:

> Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.
> Attempted configurations were:\n\tUnixSocketClientProviderStrategy:
> failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find
> unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException
> (/var/run/docker.sock)As no valid configuration was found, execution
> cannot continue.\nSee https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html
> for more details.

During valid execution I noticed the following TestContainers strategy is used:

> logger":"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy","message":"Found
> Docker environment with Environment variables, system properties and
> defaults. Resolved dockerHost=tcp://docker:2375"

I tried configuring the same strategy for the GitLab-CI:

```yaml
  before_script:
    - echo "hub.image.name.prefix=internalregistry.azurecr.io/" > $HOME/.testcontainers.properties
    - echo "docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy" >> $HOME/.testcontainers.properties
```

Unfortunatelly, even this configuration fails with the following error:

> logger":"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy","message":"Can't
> instantiate a strategy from
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy"

with the following underlying message:

> {"timestamp":"2023-12-19T09:02:21.104Z","level":"WARN","thread":"main","logger":"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy","message":"DOCKER_HOST
> tcp://docker:2375 is not listening","context":"default"}
>
> {"timestamp":"2023-12-19T09:02:21.280Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy","message":"docker-machine
> executable was not found on PATH ([/opt/java/openjdk/bin,
> /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /sbin,
> /bin])","context":"default"}
>
> {"timestamp":"2023-12-19T09:02:21.281Z","level":"ERROR","thread":"main","logger":"org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy","message":"Could
> not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.
> Attempted configurations were:\n\tUnixSocketClientProviderStrategy:
> failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find
> unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException
> (/var/run/docker.sock)As no valid configuration was found, execution
> cannot continue.\nSee https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html
> for more details.","context":"default"}

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to fix this issue and find the cause, I even tried to register the internal image as runners.docker in the GitLab runner, without any success. I asked for an exception and will be using the public image with `pull-policy: if-not-present`. I am still interested in solution, if anyone has any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

As per [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services), when defining services, a service is registered after a name is automatically inferred from the provided image:

> The default aliases for the service’s hostname are created from its
> image name following these rules:
>
> - Everything after the colon (:) is stripped.
> - Slash (/) is replaced with double underscores (__) and the primary alias is created.
> - Slash (/) is replaced with a single dash (-) and the secondary alias is created (requires GitLab Runner v1.1.0 or later).

This means, when you used the `docker:24.0.5-dind` from public hub, the created alias was `docker`. However, when you started service from image within your internal registry, the created aliases were the following:

1. `internalregistry.azurecr.io-docker`,
2. `internalregistry.azurecr.io__docker`.

Now, when you define the `DOCKER_HOST` variable:

```
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
```

you are trying to access a service named `docker`, but in your case, the only service names available are those mentioned above:

1. `internalregistry.azurecr.io-docker`,
2. `internalregistry.azurecr.io__docker`.

### The solution

You can either reconfigure your `DOCKER_HOST` variable to use the automatically inferred alias:

```
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://internalregistry.azurecr.io-docker:2375
```

or (and I would recommend this solution) set an alias, `docker`, that way the `DOCKER_HOST` remains the same and the service created from image pulled from your internal registry is registered under the value provided in the `alias` directive:

```yaml
  services:
    - name: internalregistry.azurecr.io/docker:24.0.5-dind
      alias: docker
```

Naturally, the value specified in `alias` needs to match the host specified in the `DOCKER_HOST` (or any for that matter) env variable, and vice versa.

Also ensure the image is actually the same (i.e. same SHA256 digest) as `docker:24.0.5-dind`

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution works. If you do not mind, I suggested an edit to your post, clarifying the problem and why your solution works.